# Where can i find accurate bond angles?

Tags: molecular-structure, reference-request, databases

I am trying to find places where I can have accurate bond angles of certain molecules such as $\ce{F2Se}$, $\ce{Cl2S}$, or even $\ce{S2Se}. I have looked everywhere and have found only 3 sources that give me reliable and accurate bond angles but I need a couple more.

So far I have the databases I have consulted are:

- Molview simulation
- The Cccbdb database
- Understanding trends in molecular bond angles paper
- TEACHING THE VSEPR MODEL AND ELECTRON DENSITIES.

(I am aware that Molview is a simulation.) I need this as I am writing a chemistry paper in high school where I am testing the accuracy of the VSEPR theory. According to the people correcting my paper, I need five sources in total.

Comment: Do you need five databases or just 5 sources for your paper? You could certainly use other sources that describe the theoretical background.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Chemistry SE! Now I understand your school policies, but I would recommend using sources/examples that the students are aware or something that you have discussed on the class, of it's for an exam. After all they are only students. The ones that come to top of my head is Hydrides of oxygen family, where bond angles become towards 90 deg down the group.

Comment: As noted in your previous post of this same question, search the primary literature. You can use Google Scholar for example to do this. In just one search, for example, I find this paper which has the bond angles of F2Se and Cl2S along with many others (see Table 2 in the pdf which you can download for free): https://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/apcs/apcs/2016/00000032/00000007/art00011#

Comment: Why did you [delete and repost your question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/159841/16683)? Note that single line breaks between text aren't reflected in the post. You can see for yourself that your list of sources has been condensed all into one single paragraph, which makes it difficult to read. On top of just reading the text that you type in, it's important to also check how it looks after being posted (there is even a preview screen to help you with that). Also, you should have added links to these sources, instead of making people Google them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great open access paper from 2020 on the subject:
"Understanding Trends in Molecular Bond Angles"
[*J. Phys. Chem. A* **2020**, 124, 7, 1306–1311](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpca.9b10248)

The authors calculated a wide variety of species using accurate quantum chemical methods (CASSCF/CASPT2 method, ANO-RCC basis set).

They rationalize the trends as a function of the polarizability of the atoms involved.

Not sure about $\ce{S2Se}$ but it's a nice article explaining trends in VSEPR bond angles. Maybe a bit technical in places, but the figures, tables, and supporting information are all quite detailed.

Comment: That's apparently one of OP's sources listed in their question, although I'll certainly agree the lack of formatting makes it difficult to spot. A bit annoying, because I [edited their previous version of the question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159841/where-can-i-find-accurate-bond-angles-of-molecules) to make it easier to read, only for them to delete it and repost the unedited text.